# Php array usort function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have this simple football teams array:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => MANCHESTER
            [pts] => 8
            [gd] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => BOURNEMOUTH
            [pts] => 3
            [gd] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => STOKE CITY
            [pts] => 2
            [gd] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => LIVERPOOL
            [pts] => 3
            [gd] => 5
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => ARSENAL
            [pts] => 9
            [gd] => 1
        )

)
```

- name - is teams name
- pts - total points of each team
- gd-is goal difference of each team

I want to sort teams first by `pts`, then if we have the same `pts`, sort by `gds`.

sorting only by pts we have:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b){
    return $a['pts'] - $b['pts'];
}
usort($this_is_my_array, 'sortByOrder');
```

Result array is:

```
ARSENAL (pts:9, gd:1)
MANCHESTER (pts:8, gd:5)
BOURNEMOUTH (pts:3, gd:2)
LIVERPOOL (pts:3, gd:5)
STOKE CITY (pts:2, gd:4)
```

But for `BOURNEMOUTH` & `LIVERPOOL` we have `pts` repeating, so we need to have this result:

```
ARSENAL (pts:9, gd:1)
MANCHESTER (pts:8, gd:5)
LIVERPOOL (pts:3, gd:5)
BOURNEMOUTH (pts:3, gd:2)
STOKE CITY (pts:2, gd:4)
```

Comment: @HaykMakyan _(FYI : You can accept or upvote one of these answer which really helps you.)_

Answer (score 3):

Try as

```
uasort($your_array, function($a,$b){
    $c = $b['pts'] - $a['pts'];
    $c .= $b['gd'] - $a['gd'];
    return $c;
});
print_r($your_array);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/396002)

Comment: @Uchiha i think than with two digit counts may be problem, something as  pts 11 gd 2 and  pts 1 gd 12. i am wrong, i hope

Comment: @splash58 I didn't tested it yet with those values being very tight at working schedules. I'll when I'll be free. Anyways thanks for identifying

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $array=array(
    array("name"=>"MANCHESTER","pts"=>"8","gd"=>"5"),
    array("name"=>"BOURNEMOUTH","pts"=>"3","gd"=>"2"),
    array("name"=>"STOKE CITY","pts"=>"2","gd"=>"4"),
    array("name"=>"LIVERPOOL","pts"=>"3","gd"=>"5"),
    array("name"=>"ARSENAL","pts"=>"9","gd"=>"1")
    );
  foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $searchcountvalue[$key]  = $row['name'];
    $pastsearchcountvalue[$key] = $row['pts'];
    $abstract_count[$key] = $row['gd'];   
}array_multisort($pastsearchcountvalue, SORT_DESC, $abstract_count,  SORT_DESC, $array);
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array in this format, Try check this solution.

```
    $s[] = array
        (
            'name' => 'MANCHESTER',
            'pts' => 8,
            'gd' => 5
        );

$s[] = array
        (
            'name' => 'BOURNEMOUTH',
            'pts' => 3,
            'gd' => 2
        );      
$s[] = array
        (
            'name' => 'STOKE CITY',
            'pts' => 2,
            'gd' => 4
        );

   $s[] = array
        (
            'name' => 'testing',
            'pts' => 2,
            'gd' => 6
        );

$s[] = array
        (
            'name'=> 'LIVERPOOL',
            'pts' => 3,
            'gd' => 5
        );      

$s[] = array
        (
            'name' => 'ARSENAL',
            'pts' => 9,
            'gd' => 1
        );





 function array_orderby()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $data = array_shift($args);
    foreach ($args as $n => $field) {
        if (is_string($field)) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $row)
                $tmp[$key] = $row[$field];
            $args[$n] = $tmp;
            }
    }
    $args[] = &$data;
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
    return array_pop($args);
}




$sorted = array_orderby($s, 'pts', SORT_DESC, 'gd', SORT_DESC);
```

// OutPut

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ARSENAL
            [pts] => 9
            [gd] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => MANCHESTER
            [pts] => 8
            [gd] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => LIVERPOOL
            [pts] => 3
            [gd] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => BOURNEMOUTH
            [pts] => 3
            [gd] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Testing
            [pts] => 2
            [gd] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => STOKE CITY
            [pts] => 2
            [gd] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: @HaykMakyanv can you tell me what is your requirement..because i already tested